# Storing element text in an array and accessing it later

Tags: cypress

I am trying to get element text inside a for loop for multiple elements and wanted to store it in an array in order to use it later. below is the code I am using. I needed to access the array for the later use so that i compare this array with another array. Please let me know how to achieve this in cypress.

```
  it('My test', () => {
    let arrayOfElementText = [];
    cy.get('#divEl').each(($el) => {
        cy.wrap($el).click();
        cy.get('#input').invoke('val')
            .then(val => {
                arrayOfElementText.push(val);
                console.log(arrayOfElementText);//Able to access
            });
        console.log(arrayOfElementText); **//Not able to access**
    })

    let anotherArray = [];
    cy.get('#divEl1').each(($el) => {
        cy.get('#input1').invoke('val')
            .then(val => {
                anotherArray.push(val);
                console.log(anotherArray);//Able to access
            });
        console.log(anotherArray);**//Not able to access**
    })
    // code to compare two arrays 
    //both arrays are not accessible here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.then()` to access the values, as they are derived from asynchronous commands.

```js
let arrayOfElementText = [];

cy.get('#divEl').each(($el) => {
  cy.wrap($el).click();
  cy.get('#input').invoke('val')
    .then(val => {
      arrayOfElementText.push(val);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(arrayOfElementText); // array is available at every step of .each()
    })
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(arrayOfElementText); // full array is available here
    cy.wrap(arrayOfElementText).as('myArray1')  // alias it for later
  })

/* 
  Next array, same as above
*/

cy.get('@myArray1').then(myArray1 => {
  cy.get('@myArray2').then(myArray2 => {
    // compare
  })
})
```

**Note** `cy.get('#input')` will always get the same input